# PHP mail subject

Tags: php, email, sendmail

I need a little help here. I'm trying to send an email using the simple php `mail()`. My subject has chinese characters. When I send the email, I get this:

`ä¿®æ”¹å¯†ç  - å‘˜å·¥è‡ªåŠ©æœåŠ¡ç³»ç»Ÿ`

But, it should be like this:

`修改密码 - 员工自助服务系统`

Here's the code:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: Me<me@email.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Subject :  修改密码 - 员工自助服务系统' . "\r\n";
mail("sample@email.com", '修改密码 - 员工自助服务系统', "sample message ",$headers);
```

Comment: how you are deriving subject? is it from database?

Comment: Maybe you should use another another charset `utf-16` or can you give information about the email client you are using to view the mails?

Comment: @Animesh-the-coder, why did you remove half the code from this question and leave the comment that says "additional headers"...?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your file is encoded as UTF8, open your script with your editor and save as UTF8.
Second way is to use PHPMailer() :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->MsgHTML($htmlBody);
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8"; // here you set the charset
```